# I have implemented mergesort in python, but it gives me a "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" error

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I tried implementing mergesort in python, but on the "mergesort" function where I check if the sorting is done it gives me a maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison error. I know that this means it repeats the function too much, but I have no idea what is causing it or how to fix it. I've tried tweaking some settings but nothing seems to work. Code and error is provided below.

```
def mergesort(arr, start, end):
    if start > end:
        return

    middle = (start + end) // 2

    mergesort(arr, start, middle)
    mergesort(arr, middle + 1, end)

    return merge(arr, start, end, middle)

def merge(arr, start, end, middle):
    leftCopy = arr[start:middle]
    rightCopy = arr[middle + 1:end]

    leftIndex = 0
    rightIndex = 0

    sortedIndex = start

    while leftIndex < len(leftCopy) and rightIndex < len(rightCopy):
        if leftCopy[leftIndex] > rightCopy[rightIndex]:
            arr[sortedIndex] = leftCopy[leftIndex]
            leftIndex += 1
        else:
            arr[sortedIndex] = rightCopy[rightIndex]
            rightIndex += 1

        sortedIndex += 1

    while leftIndex < len(leftCopy):
        arr[sortedIndex] = leftCopy[leftIndex]
        leftIndex += 1
        sortedIndex += 1

    while rightIndex < len(rightCopy):
        arr[sortedIndex] = rightCopy[rightIndex]
        rightIndex += 1
        sortedIndex += 1

sample = [3, 1, 2]

mergesort(sample, 0, len(sample) - 1)
print(sample)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mergesort.py", line 43, in <module>
    mergesort(sample, 0, len(sample) - 1)
  File "mergesort.py", line 7, in mergesort
    mergesort(arr, start, middle)
  File "mergesort.py", line 7, in mergesort
    mergesort(arr, start, middle)
  File "mergesort.py", line 7, in mergesort
    mergesort(arr, start, middle)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "mergesort.py", line 2, in mergesort
    if start > end:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: What happens when `start==end`?

Comment: I tried using start == end or start <= end, but it just didn't sort the list at all or do any operations on it

Comment: Have you verified that your `merge` works correctly?

Comment: I think there's a problem with that function but I couldn't figure out what it was. I just now realised I accidentally put ">" instead of "<", but it's still not working correctly after changing that. If you could look over the code and tell me if you find an issue it'd be great

Answer (score 0):

Your base case does not cover when `start==end` (which it should: a 1-element list cannot be out of order); in that case, `middle`=`start`, *so the first recursive call is identical to the current one* -- hence the unending recursion.

Comment: alright, thanks, could you tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: if I check for start==end the list isn't sorted at all, or (it seems to be) is randomly sorted, so I think there's an issue in the merge function as well, but I can't figure out what it is.

EDIT: so it turns out I messed up an if statement and used ">" instead of "<", but now it doesn't sort the 3 number list example I gave in my post and for longer lists it looks like some sections of the list are sorted and some aren't.